An approximate lower bound for options on variance
Question:
I am wondering if anybody has looked at the following lower bound, based on the most-likely path approximation, and/or tested it?
Let $dS_t = \sigma_t S_t dW_t$, where $\sigma_t$ is a stochastic spot vol.
Options on variance lower bound:
\begin{align}
E \left[ \left( \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt - l \right)_+ \right] &= \int_0^\infty E \left[ \left.\left( \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt - l \right)_+ \right| S_T=K \right] p(K) dK \\
&\geq \int_0^\infty \left( E \left[ \left. \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt \right| S_T=K \right] - l \right)_+ \; p(K) dK \\
&\approx \int_0^\infty \left( I^2(K,T) - l \right)_+ \; p(K) dK. \\
\end{align}
where the last step uses the MLP approximation.
I'm really curious if this gives a reasonable lower bound. As I cannot find any papers on this and this is quite an easy approx to derive, my guess is that it doesn't work that well. But just double checking here at QFSE.
